# Minimize absolute deviation from volatility target - portfolio optimization - Python

Tags: python, optimization, absolute, cvxopt

I have the below portfolio optimization problem that I need to specify in python (using cvxopt or any other optimization package). I am unable to figure out how to specify a problem containing absolute value in the objective function. The problem tries to minimize the difference between portfolio volatility and a target volatility by optimizing the constituent weights. The problem is expressed as below

```
    Min |xTΣx – σ2target|

    s.t. 

    1Tx = 1
    x >= 0
```

where 
Σ is the covariance matrix, and
σ<sub>target</sub> is the volatility target (5%, for example)

How do I formulate the above problem in python ? I currently use cvxopt for general QP-type problems.

Comment: Do you need to minimize this specific function? can't you minimize 
 (xΣx – σ²)² ?

Comment: yes. that would work as well. is there a way to specify this problem using cvxopt, given that its a higher order polynomial involving a covariance matrix and a constant?